# ¿Cómo crear un List de setters y getters en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Así luce en java, tengo pasarlo a python y no tenga idea de como hacerlo.

```
public List<Archivo> getArchivos() {     

   return archivos;

    }


    public void setArchivos(List<Archivo> archivos) {
        this.archivos = archivos;
    }
```

y llevo esto en python :

```
class ResponseUpdateDTO(object):

def set_serial(self,serial):
    self._serial = serial
@property
def get_serial(self):
    return self._serial

def set_synergy(self,value):
    self._synergy = value
@property
def get_synergy(self):
    return self._synergy


def set_responseAzure(self,value):
    self._responseAzure = value

@property
def get_responseAzure(self):
    return self._responseAzure

#falta list de archivo
```

Comment: Pues necesito pasar un proyecto java a python y en los dto se utiliza setters y getters  en lista

Comment: Los setters y gettters no son la mejor opcion para el lenguaje, una alternativa mejor es usar properties

Comment: Necesito hacer lo de esa forma, con setters y getters

Comment: Si pero idiomaticamente no es correcto, muchas veces no se deben hacer traducciones de manera literal entre lenguajes de programacion, se puede implementar un funcionamiento similar usando lo adecuado para cada lenguaje, puedes revisar esta informacion http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Comment: Pues lo he hecho tal como lo muestra en el ejemplo que me mostrastes solo que tenga la duda de como seria con listas. Es que despues necesito obtenerlo y recorrer la lista.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primero que nada, no hay `getters` o `setters` al estilo Java en **Python**. No hay forma, no existen. Se puede hacer algo parecido, si, sin duda, pero lo que hagamos no va a tener nunca la filosofía de **Java**. Hay un concepto que describe bien la diferencias en este sentido entre ambos lenguajes, lo puedes encontrar mencionados en muchos lugares, y es la idea del "Programador Malvado", en **Java** hay un encapsulamiento muy fuerte en los objetos, ciertas propiedades las podemos acceder solo mediante los métodos apropiados, la idea es que en Java se cuida a los objetos de este hipotético Programador Malvado, en **Python** esa idea se la reemplaza por un: "somos todos adultos", es decir cada uno sabe lo que está haciendo, si quieres modificar un atributo interno de un objeto, perfecto, se supone que sabes lo que estás haciendo. Por favor que nadie malinterprete esto, es simplemente una metáfora para describir las diferencias en cuanto a esta pregunta y entre ambos lenguajes, ninguna cosa es mejor que la otra, son distintas concepciones. Todo esto para volver a recalcar "no hay `getters` o `setters` al estilo Java en **Python**", por más esfuerzo que le pongamos, siempre pero siempre tendremos alguna forma de acceder a los atributos internos de un objeto. Dicho esto, vayamos a tu pregunta en particular:

Voy a reescribir tu código para simplificarlo, definimos la clase `ResponseUpdateDTO`, a tener dos atributos `serial` que en principio podría ser un string, y `archivos`, que será una lista.

```
class ResponseUpdateDTO(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._serial = ""
        self._archivos = []        

    def set_serial(self, serial):
        self._serial = serial

    def get_serial(self):
        return self._serial

    def get_archivos(self):
        return self._archivos

    def set_archivos(self, archivos):
        self._archivos = archivos
```

Algunos comentarios:

- Es conveniente la mayoría de las veces definir el método `__init__`, no es un constructor, es simplemente uno de los primeros métodos que se ejecuta al instanciarse un objeto y por convención se suele inicializar aquí todos los atributos del objeto, también eventualmente se definen en los parámetros, que atributos se pasan en la inicialización.
- Otra convención que has usado muy bien es nombrar atributos y métodos con el guión bajo `_` delante, con esto le decimos a cualquier otro programador: "mira, estos datos y estas funciones no las uses por favor", de hecho se quitan automáticamente de la documentación que podrías obtener mediante `help()`, pero no quiere decir que no puedan usarse.
- Como puedes ver además, el pseudo `getter` y `setter` para los archivos no difiere de los otros que has definido.

Claramente como está ahora el código, podrías hacer:

```
r = ResponseUpdateDTO()
r.set_archivos(['archivo1', 'archivo2'])
print(r.get_archivos())
```

Pero también puedes hacer esto:

```
r._archivos = ['archivo1', 'archivo2']
```

Claramente no hay encapsulamiento, estás accediendo directamente al atributo `_archivos` que imaginamos privado, de hecho si tu `setter` tiene alguna lógica de validación, esta no estaría ejecutándose. 
Originalmente has intentado usar ["decoradores"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) para acercarte a la funcionalidad que esperas ver y efectivamente vas por el buen camino. Veamos como usarlos y que podemos lograr realmente:

```
class ResponseUpdateDTO(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._serial = ""
        self._archivos = []        

    @property
    def serial(self):
        return self._serial

    @serial.setter
    def serial(self,serial):
        self._serial = serial

    @property
    def archivos(self):
        return self._archivos

    @archivos.setter
    def archivos(self, archivos):
        self._archivos = archivos


r = ResponseUpdateDTO()

r.archivos = ['archivo1', 'archivo2']
print(r.archivos)
```

#### ¿Que hemos logrado con esto?

- En primer lugar el método `archivos` se comportará como getter o
  setter en función de como lo usemos
- Podremos incorporar lógica, en particular al setter, por ejemplo para validar los datos ingresados.

Pero, como dije al principio, siempre cabe la posibilidad de hacer esto:

```
r._archivos =  ['archivo1', 'archivo2']
print(r._archivos)
```

Pero como el concepto en Python es que todos somos adultos no debería ser un problema demasiado grande, aún así, hay una forma de impedir hacer lo anterior, que es nombrar todas las variables privadas con el doble guión bajo `__`, por ejemplo:

```
    @archivos.setter
    def archivos(self, archivos):
        self.__archivos = archivos
```

De esta forma, al hacer esto:

```
r._archivos =  ['archivo1', 'archivo2']
```

Obtendrás una hermosa Excepcion:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 29, in
>    AttributeError: 'ResponseUpdateDTO' object has no attribute
>   '__archivos'

Esto es nada más que un truco, lo que hace el interprete en estos casos, es "renombrar" internamente la variable como `_classname__archivos`, por lo que también podrías eventualmente hacer

```
r._ResponseUpdateDTO__archivos = ['archivo1', 'archivo2']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de ayuda!

Comment: **MUY** buena explicación! Sobre todo para un novato en python como yo, ahora me ayudo a entender un par de cosas que no tenia claras. Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para que la explicación sea clara y consisa y sin muchas vueltas.

Answer (score 4):

Como ya te han comentado no es buena idea en general realizar una traducción literal de un lenguaje a otro. Nada impide que lo hagas, y puedes hacerlo tal y como te indica Daniel Diaz en su respuesta si lo deseas.

En Python no existen como tal el concepto de "setter" o "getter" al uso de Java. En tu caso, sin validar nada en la entrada o sin modificar para nada la salida no tienen sentido los métodos "get" y "set" en Python, bastaría con algo como:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.archivos = []
```

Teniendo una instancia de la clase:

```
>>> instancia = MyClass()
```

Podemos asignar un valor simplemente con:

```
>>> instancia.archivos = ['hola', 'mundo']
```

Y obtenerlo con:

```
>>> instancia.archivos
['hola', 'mundo']
```

Podemos obtener y modificar de forma libre y directa los atributos, se presupone que sabemos lo que hacemos, sin necesidad de ponernos el cartel de "prohibido acceder/modificar, esto es privado". La idea de los getters y setters es validar o formatear la salida de alguna forma y/o mantener la encapsulacion de los datos. Para ello lo más apropiado y simple  es usar el decorador [**`@property`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Supongamos que el atributo `archivos` debe ser una lista de objetos de una supuesta clase `Archivo`, podemos usar el "setter" para comprobar el tipo de la entrada si fuera necesario:

```
class Archivo(object):
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._archivos = []

    @property
    def archivos(self):
        return self._archivos

    @archivos.setter
    def archivos(self, archivos):
        if isinstance(archivos, list) and all(isinstance(e, Archivo) for e in archivos):
            self._archivos = archivos
        else:
            raise ValueError('archivos debe ser una lista de instancias de Archivo')
```

**Ejemplo de uso:**

- Instanciamos nuestra clase:

  ```
  >>> instancia = MyClass()
  ```
- Asignamos una lista de instancias de Archivo al atributo `archivos` ("setter"):

  ```
  >>> instancia.archivos = [Archivo(), Archivo()]
  ```
- Obtenemos el valor del atributo ("getter"):

  ```
  >>> instancia.archivos
  [<__main__.Archivo object at 0x0000018BEE9CBAC8>, <__main__.Archivo object at 0x0000018BEEA58128>]
  ```
- Intentamos pasarle valores no válidos al atributo `archivos`:

  ```
  >>> instancia.archivos = 14
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
      instancia.archivos = 14
    File ""D:\prueba.py"", line 18, in archivos
      raise ValueError('archivos debe ser una lista de instancias de Archivo')
  ValueError: archivos debe ser una lista de instancias de Archivo

  >>> instancia.archivos = ['Hola', "Mundo"]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
      instancia.archivos = ['Hola', "Mundo"]
    File "D:\prueba.py", line 18, in archivos
      raise ValueError('archivos debe ser una lista de instancias de Archivo')
  ValueError: archivos debe ser una lista de instancias de Archivo
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho en mi aprendizaje en python

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado un ejemplo por internet:

```
class ser_humano(object):
   def __init__(self, edad, altura, peso):
       self.__edad=edad
       self.__altura=altura
       self.__peso=peso

   def getPeso(self):
       return self.__peso

   def setPeso(self, peso = None):
       self.__peso = peso

   def getAltura(self):
       return self.__altura

   def setAltura(self, altura = None):
       self.__altura = altura

   def getEdad(self):
       return self.__edad

   def setEdad(self, edad = None):
       self.__edad = edad
```

Fuente: http://elviajedelnavegante.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/las-propiedades-property-de-python.html