# Como definir un atributo de tipo DateTime en pyton

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, stored-procedure, atributos

quisiera saber como establecer atributos en python dentro de una clase. E intentado el siguiente codigo:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.fecha_Y_Hs = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.decripcion = ''
```

Soy nuevo en este lenguaje y me gustaria saber como puedo declarar y almacenar en MySQL ultilizando un metodo para guardar utilizando **callproc()**, hasta el momento tengo esto:

Metodo **guardar()**

```
def guardar(self):
    try:
        conn = self.conexionMySQL()
        myCursor = conn.cursor()
        arg = [self.getfechaActual(), self.getDescripcion()]
        myCursor.callproc('insertar_registro', arg)
        conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Se produjo el siguiente error al guardar: ", e)
        finally:
            myCursor.close()
            conn.close()
```

Dentro de la lista llamo a los metodos **getfechaActual()** y **getDescripcion()** que son los parametros que necesitaria para guardar en mi bbdd. Pero no me funsiona.

Metodos **getfechaActual()** y **getDescripcion()**

```
def getfechaActual(self):
    return self.fecha_Y_Hs

def getDescripcion(self):
    return self.descripcion
```

Necesitaria saber como puedo declarar mis atributos correctamente para que luego pueda pasarle los parametros necesarios para ser almacenados en la bbdd. Asi luego desde otro metodo llamar a **guardar()**.

Por ej:

```
def nombre_metodo(param):

    if condicion:
       ...
       guardar()
```

Esto mismo en **Java** se hace seteando los **Get** And **Setter** pero aqui nose como hacerlo ya que estoy crudo en el tema, me falta un golpe de horno fuerte. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Hola Gerardo, el concepto de setters y getters no existe como tal en Python, puedes desde el método `guardar` usar el atributo directamente sin problemas `arg = [self.fecha_Y_Hs, self.descripcion]`. Si necesitas realmente la funcionalidad de un setter o getter la respuesta de Python son las propiedades. [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100845/15089) puede serte de ayuda.

Comment: De cualquier forma tu código no es incorrecto en si en principio, en cuanto a obtener el atributo al menos, otra cosa es que el objeto`datetime` sea aceptado sin más por la db si el adaptador que uses para la conexión no realiza la conveniente conversión, en tal caso pasar una cadena con el formato adecuado puedes ser la solución por ejemplo `self.fecha_Y_Hs.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no funciona?¿alguna excepción?

Comment: @FJSevilla Me sirvio tu comentario, el primero me aclaro muchas dudas, exelente. Te agradezco mucho! Cn respecto a mi cod. lo q queria era hacer un metodo **guardar()**  SIN parametros, porq me quedaba feo, entonces lo que necesitaba era setear de alguna forma mis atributos antes de almacenarlo en la **lista** de esta forma **self.setfechaActual(self.__fechaHs)
  self.setDescripcion(self.__descripcion)** En la lista llamar a mis metodos **self.getfechaActual(), self.getDescripcion()** d esa  forma obtengo ls datos almacenados en mis atributos. Desde otro metodo de la clase llamo al guardar()

Comment: Dentro de ese metodo, previamente antes de llamar a mi metodo **guardar()** establesco los valores a mis atributos de clase inicializados en vacio en el **__init()__**, en este caso, almaceno una fecha y una cadena. Quedando **self.__fechaHs = datetime.datetime.now()
                    self.__descripcion = "Automovil" ** seguido de la llamada de mi metodo **guardar()**. Nose si e sido claro pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos